# MSTest & CruiseControl.Net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I am trying to get MSTest working with CruiseControl.Net. I currently have it working prefectly for unit tests, but I would like to see my code coverage. When I run MSTest and export it to an XML file (using /resultsfile:"C:\output\results.xml") it seems that no Coverage information is exported. However when I run MS test and open the result TRX file, it contains all of the code coverage information. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include the [MsTestSummary.xsl](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+MSTest) in your web dashboard configuration?

EDIT: Code Coverage report is not supported, you'll have to modify the xsl file yourself (and preferably attach your changes to a bug report so that other users can benefit).

Comment: Yes, I have added this. (MSTestSummary2008.xsl becuase I am using tfs 2k8). This is what gives me the details of my Unit Tests, however does not give me anything on my code coverage.